# Prove that $R(Q_d) \leq 2^{3d}$, where $R(Q_d)$ is the Ramsey number of the $d$-dimensional hypercube $Q_d$.

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, ramsey-theory, probabilistic-method, extremal-graph-theory

I want to try a probabilistic proof for this problem. Please give some comments on this attempt at a proof.

Let $G$ be our complete graph $K_{2^{3d}}$, with the edges colored red/blue randomly and independently. My observation is that, any $d$-dimensional cube $Q_d$ can be constructed from $2$ copies of $Q_{d-1}$, with the missing edges added appropriately. Since $2^{3d} = 2^{3(d-1)}\cdot 8$, by induction $G$ contains $8$ copies of monochromatic $Q_{d-1}$, at least $4$ of which must be of the same color (wlog let the color be red).

Now consider the event $X$ that none of the pair of $Q_{d-1}$ among those $4$ copies form a monochromatic red $Q_d$. This is the union of the events that all pairs of $Q_{d-1}$ are invalid. By the union bound, we have:
$$\mathbb{P}(X) \leq \sum \mathbb{P} \text{(the pair of $Q_{d-1}$ forms invalid $Q_d$)} = {4 \choose 2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2^{d-1}} = \frac{6}{2^{2^{d-1}}} < 1, \text{ for $d>1$.}$$

Hence the probability that one of the pair of $Q_{d-1}$ forms a valid, monochromatic red $Q_d$ is strictly positive.

—————————————
**Edit:** I’m putting up a bounty for this question. Hints or answers would be appreciated.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the proof-verification tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This proof does not work. The probability that any edge causes the pair of $Q_{d-1}$ to be invalid is $1/2$, so the probability that there is an edge that causes it to be invalid is one minus the probability that *all* edges are valid, that is
$$1-\left(\frac12\right)^{2^{d-1}}.$$
This number is unfortunately way too large for the probabilistic proof to carry through.

Comment: The following idea might not work as well, but I want to know why, so please have a look. Let $Y$ be the random variable counting the number of valid pairs amongst the $4$ copies of $Q_{d-1}$. Then by linearity of expectation, we have $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum \mathbb{E}[Y_i] = {4 \choose 2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2^{d-1}}$, where $Y_i$ is the indicator variable for the pair indexed $i$. This quantity is surely greater than $0$ (and since $Y$ is discrete, we’d have $\mathbb{E}[Y] \geq 1$).

Comment: @ensbana If I'm understanding what you're saying, $\mathbb E[Y]$ is less than $1$, but more than $0$, so $Y$ is certainly positive somewhere. However, I don't see how $Y$ being positive somewhere actually helps you: it just tells you that there exists a coloring of $K_{2^{3d}}$ with a monochromatic $Q_d$, which is not what you want.